# Docker Python Script Random Files Not Found, Failures

Tags: python, docker

I've been running the same python script in a Docker environment for about the last year now with no major issues.

About a month ago I updated to Docker 4.25.0 and ever since then, my python script has not worked.

I feel like I've fixed a bit of the problems but this last file access issue has been driving me crazy!

Here is an example of the code that seems to keep failing:

```
for f in os.listdir(taskOutputFolder):
    if not f.startswith('.'):
        if f.endswith('.zip'):
            print("\n")
            print("***************************************")
            print(f"Zip File Found! {f}")
            print("***************************************")
            src_file = self.fileCheck(taskOutputFolder, f)
            dest_file = os.path.join(nextTaskInputFolder , f)

            # Copy File To Task's Output Folder
            print(f"Copying file {f} from {taskOutputFolder} to {nextTaskInputFolder}")
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(src_file, dest_file)
                print(f"Successfully copied {f} to {nextTaskInputFolder}.")

            except Exception as ex:
                print(f"Failed to copy {src_file} to {dest_file} with error:")
                print(ex)
```

Before the above code, I use:

```
with ZipFile(zip_out_filepath, mode="w", compression=ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9) as archive:
    for file_path in Path(zip_in_filepath).iterdir():
        archive.write(file_path, arcname=file_path.name)
```

To create a .zip file and then before, after, and during each of these functions I've been using:

```
 def fileCheck(self, fileFolder, fileName):
        
    file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(fileFolder, fileName))
    print(f'Checking File Status for {file}...')

    # Check for bad file naming characters and remove any whitespace if found
    badFileNameChars = ['(', ')', ' ', ',', '\t']
    res = any(ele in fileName for ele in badFileNameChars)
    if res:
        print(f'Found Bad File Name Characters In: {fileName}')
        file = self.cleanFileName(file)

    # Check If File Copy Was Successfull
    retries = 0
    file_found = False
    while not file_found:
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            retries += 1
            print(f'\nWaiting For File To Exist: {file}...')
            print(f'Retry: {retries}...\n')
            time.sleep(5)
            if retries > 6:
                file_found = True
        else:
            file_stats = os.stat(file)
            print(f'File Found: {file}')
            print(f'File Stats: {file_stats}')
            file_found = True

    return file
```

To try and verify that the file exists and is accessible...

Then when I run the script, I get this error:

```
Checking File Status for /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...

File Found: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip
File Stats: os.stat_result(st_mode=33279, st_ino=60, st_dev=40, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=380537, st_atime=1700345226, st_mtime=1700345215, st_ctime=1700345215)

Checking Zip Output Again For Delayed Completion Check... 
Checking File Status for /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...


Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 1...

Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 2...

Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 3...

Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 4...

Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 5...

Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 6...

Waiting For File To Exist: /mnt/preprocessing-out/preprocess-pipe-local.zip...
Retry: 7...


***********************************************************
[Sat Nov 18 22:08:16 2023] [CRITICAL_FAILURE] - Missing output file after running ZIP Function
```

Here is the code that caused the above error:

```
with ZipFile(zip_out_filepath, mode="w", compression=ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9) as archive:
    for file_path in Path(zip_in_filepath).iterdir():
        archive.write(file_path, arcname=file_path.name)

zip_out_filepath = self.fileCheck(Path(zip_out_filepath).parent, os.path.basename(zip_out_filepath))

print('Checking Zip Output Again For Delayed Completion Check... ')
time.sleep(5)

zip_out_filepath = self.fileCheck(Path(zip_out_filepath).parent, os.path.basename(zip_out_filepath))

assert os.path.isfile(zip_out_filepath), 'Missing output file after running ZIP Function: '
```

I've tried creating the functions above that checks that the file exists and is accessible.

I've tried switch from command line zip functions to python ZipFile module functions.

I've tried renaming files and trying to work with the newly named files.

I just cant figure out why everything that I know how to do says the file is right there and available but the very next line in the script says the file cant be found... Please help!

I think the problem has to do with Docker since the only thing that really changed was the update to 4.25.0 but I'm still pretty new to Docker and unsure how to diagnose the problem. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction for a solution or maybe help me understand what Docker changed that could be causing my random file access errors.

Comment: Also, I'm running on a mac and the Docker mounted volume is held on an external hard drive. I've considered that this might be part of my issue but it has been running this exact way for probably over a year now and never had this problem. Also I've given Docker 16 CPU, 32gb Ram, and 125GB HD allocations so it shouldnt be running out of resources.

Comment: Why does this code call `self.fileCheck()` twice? Presumably, if it returns because it finds a file, the file will still exist five seconds later. Why was this code originally written? Is there something that can cause this file to stop existing?

Comment: With regard to the `with ZipFile(...) as archive:` bit: it seems like you're checking for this file to exist before exiting the context manager for the zip file. Many Python libraries delay finishing disk IO until the context manager exits. Have you tried dedenting `zip_out_filepath = self.fileCheck(Path(zip_out_filepath).parent, os.path.basename(zip_out_filepath))` by one level so that it runs after this context manager exits?

Comment: Hey Nick, It is de-dented by one level, not sure why it showed up weird on here. Also the self.fileCheck() is called twice initially so I could check the file size at 2 different times to see if the file was slow to fully complete the zip process but it ended up being a good example of the problem I'm having since the first self.fileCheck() call worked just fine and literally 5 seconds later on the next line, the script fails to find the exact same file the first self.fileCheck was just able to find.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in the question? It will make it easier to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, fixed the indentation.

Comment: Try checking if the file does exist inside the container. There are several ways you can do this. `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash` and inside the container `cd` to the directory of the zip file and see if its there with `ls` or you can just `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> ls /mnt/preprocessing-out/` and your .zip should be listed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by moving the mounted volume and all working files to the local hard drive rather than an external hard drive. Still not sure how the file goes from found to missing, or why it worked before on the external hard drive but now fails, but everything seems to run without error when not using an external hard drive.